# How can I add a watermark on videos before uploading them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, watermark, video-watermarking

I have an ASP.NET application (Web App) that uploads videos to a server and I want to put my watermark on the videos. I have searched a lot for libraries that do this but found nothing, only watermarking on images.

So is there any easy way to do this? To process the videos before uploading by adding watermark on them then upload the video to the server I want?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a .NET component, consider using ffmpeg as a separate process started from your web app: http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but sharing the below link with you. Maybe it would help you:-

[WatermarkLink](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/379910/Adding-a-watermark-to-Video-and-Audio-Files)